# Upload failed. There was an error uploading the Android App Bundle

Tags: android, google-play, apk, release

Hope you are better than me at this moment. My boss told me to release our app on PlayStore but I get this msg all the time:

Upload failed. There was an error uploading the Android App Bundle. Try again later or contact Google Play developer support if the error persists.

Looking forward to any advice.

Thank you all.

Comment: Have you contacted Google Play support like the error suggests?

Comment: Yes, I have done it but not feedback :/

Comment: Google Play support told me to try the following:
- clearing the browser cache and cookies
- uploading the app using incognito mode
- using a different browser (I was using Chrome originally)
None of these tips helped me, but perhaps they will work for you.
I'm still waiting for a working solution from the support team.